How To Avoid Pushing a Personal Philosophy
Be nice
A reminder that we should keep discussions polite and without accusing or insulting people. I know VTC is a contentious topic but my hope is that by discussing it we can hopefully reduce the number of times people want to use it, by improving the quality of questions (and thus answers) overall.
I also feel really strongly that having questions VTC'd isn't a mark against somebody's character. I've had a lot of questions closed across different network sites--nobody should see a question closed and think less of the user who asked it.
Where we stand:
I'm hoping to put together some guidelines and guidance about this close reason:

Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them.

And related, this paragraph from the help center:

Please note that this site is not a personal blog or a pulpit for you to express your own personal philosophical beliefs. This is a Q&A site for examining ideas and concepts in the field of philosophy. It's OK to have opinions (even those that might differ from the "mainstream"), but you need to express them in a constructive way. If you fail to do this, your contributions are subject to being edited or moderated so that they adopt a less hostile or confrontational point of view.

Aren't we all pushing stuff?
I think this meta answer from Frank Hubeny here fits my personal experience pretty well:

I see all questions that are not homework exercises as a kind of "Test My Theory" question. Or, to put it in other words, they are motivated otherwise they wouldn't be asked at all and they come from some perspective on what the person asking the question already thinks is true.

This rings true to me, at least for questions I've asked. This question I asked because I was convinced that aesthetics was no longer (or never was) the domain of philosophy, and I wanted to see if anybody could convince me otherwise. It's a "prove me wrong" question in all but name. I'm also asking the prospective respondent to buy into assumptions of my worldview: "Suppose aesthetic sense can be reduced to a problem of statistics. What then?" People in the comments justifiably pointed out that that might be a wildly implausible assumption. (What if the world were made of pudding?!)
At the same time, that question didn't attract any close votes for pushing-a-philosophy. What gives?
"Feels pushy"
I think the list of things that feel (at least to some of us?) like "pushing a personal philosophy" are significantly wider than the close reason's explanation of "essentially a blog post". (I'm judging this based on my own inclinations, the types of questions that attract this close vote, and the discussions in the related meta threads.)
Some of these are worse than others, but here's a non-exhaustive list of things that I've considered clicking the "vote to close as pushing-philosophy" button (or making an edit) because of:

The question is an afterthought to a blog post, e.g. "What do you think?"
The tone of the question is exceptionally combative or unkind.
The asker argues with any answers to try and explain why they're dumb and wrong.
The only answer that seems acceptable is "yeah, I guess you're right". (Phrasings like "couldn't one argue that...?"--yeah, you could, I guess.)
The baseline assumptions, explicit or implicit, feel extremely narrow and unnatural without "good reason".
The asker does not acknowledge the assumptions they're making when pointed out to them. (Here I'm thinking of e.g. on a question that presupposes the nonexistence of God, somebody saying "for the record, one common answer to this is God", replying "yeah, my question is specifically about the non-God answer" compared to "everybody knows God isn't real".)
The question, while not explicitly a duplicate, is retreading ground without "good reason".

Note that a bunch of these are subjective issues with tone, not substance. Many essentially have "it's fine if I like it, though" stapled onto them. Ultimately I think it comes back to "this doesn't feel like it's actually a question". I'm not pleased with how "squishy" that definition is--it leaves a lot of room for "VTC because I don't like the writing style of the author". Though the issue of tone does get repeated in Help Center: Don't Ask:

[DON'T]: your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”
[DO]: have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.

The "arguing in comments" bullet point also seems different and difficult to me because it's not an issue with the text of the question, it's an issue with the mindset it was posed in.
Feedback please?

First off, I'm curious if my "feels pushy" list feels about right to people, or if you apply significantly different metrics.
Secondly, any 'best practices' do you feel for making a question that doesn't feel pushy? (In particular, I think a good metric might be to look for questions where you totally disagree with the premise but find the question well-posed? E.g. I know I've seen some theology-related questions that I (lifelong atheist) thought asked insightful questions that didn't feel 'pushy'.)
If you've run afoul of your question being closed for pushing-a-philosophy, was it clear what other people objected to, and how you could fix it?
Is there a way to improve the phrasing of the close reason? Should the actual scope of the close reason be broadened or narrowed?

(The irony of me writing "Questions that are just an argument with 'what do you think?' stapled to the end suck! What do you think?" is not lost on me.)
Related:

Subjective answers and questions stimulating subjectiveness : 2013 post about how to handle "is X" vs "which philosophers claim X" questions.
Questions if arguments or interpretations are correct : 2017 post on how to handle "am I wrong?" questions and the spectrum they exist on.
'Test My Theory' style questions
Can I ask a question to answer it, instead of pushing a personal philosophy?
How can I improve this question about the justification of logic?
Are we allowed to express our own opinions?
Reference requests and "personal philosophy"
An ever-relevant phil.SE meta post: Friends, we are not philosophers
The classic SE blogpost: Good Subjective, Bad Subjective


Tnx for taking the initiative on this. It's long overdue. I'll need a few days to put my thoughts on this... but for now just this tnx!

The reality is that any of the factors that involve closing a question can be shoehorned after the fact. For example, a more pertinent issue in my eyes is the idea of what constitutes as an “opinion based” question. But almost every single question on the site that doesn’t explicitly ask for a philosopher’s take on a topic, or a definitional question, can be interpreted to be “opinion based”. This allows people to VTC a question on a topic they personally  don’t like and fall back on “well, it’s opinion based” even if they don’t VTC another question that seems to be equally opinion based

@MisterMiyagi what we want to find out is affected by what we already find plausible and interesting. I don't ask about ontological arguments bc it isn't in the realm of "plausible enough to be interesting" to me.

@MisterMiyagi I feel like a look at my answers makes it pretty clear that most of my answers are from perspectives I disagree with, just making the argument as best I can for another perspective

@MisterMiyagi "Here are my current beliefs. Please poke holes in them" is an excellent way to find out what is true. You don't need to start with a blank slate to move in the right direction. (And nobody starts with a blank slate, anyway. Better to explicitly acknowledge the assumptions that are going to be there whether stated or not.)

At one point recently I commented that it seemed OP was asking the question "in bad faith". What I mean by that is basically 'motivated reasoning' and, not disclosing one's intentions. Now, that is feeling-based, unfortunately, but might explain a lot of downvotes and VTC if others feel it too. No one wants to handle issues that smell funny. (Except comedians) Faith may be "the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen", but I would rather not just feed someone's hopes and misperceptions. Psychology is the place for that. (Well, dashing them)

I wanted to make some kind of post as a public service announcement, so here is my opportunity:

"Please Do Not Feed The Bears"

When you see a Question that follows directly from one the same user asked yesterday with a small adjustment or, especially, a recent quote from another user on this site, please just don't Comment, don't Answer, don't Edit. Just, don't.
The endless whirl of trying to strain gnats from the hurricane is really tiresome. Duck and cover. If it quacks like a duck, don't answer the doorbell. Don't start salivating, or whatever. Don't respond.

The Post Man always rings, twice. Make that 80 times...

You should also down vote if you think that makes it a poor question. There is some debate as to if that makes the question one you should vote to close, but questions that don't meet the quality standards of the site should be closed.

Note that the standard Stack Exchange concerns apply. "An assertion is not a Question" is core SE policy, for example. Yes, the exact line is unclear; reality is messy and humans more so. And yes, since that's a matter of form (not firm, I hate this keyboard) it can often be rescued by separating the question and the preemptive arguments, moving the latter into an answer. And yes, that's arbitrary but that's SE.
Much of SE also expects the asker to have made at least some effort to resolve the question themselves via searching the web and prior answers, though that's inconsistently applied. As has been noted before, close-as-duplicate is a lot less controversial, though again the line is fuzzy and sometimes it would really help to explain why it's considered a duplicate.

Most people who spend some time on SE are well aware of these SE rules/concerns. But you (and others) are steering clear from addressing the main issue here. The function of closing or deleting someone's posts is usually reserved for moderators. Now, if you are expecting ordinary participants to take on the role of moderating resource content, then it has to be well thought of and carefully balanced policy. And if this feature becomes a weapon of choice in ideological wars, then there should be some fallback to mitigate it.

On stack exchange, for good or ill, the function of closing someone's posts is crowdsourced, with review by the moderators. So is the function of reopening, and of editing, though outright deletion can only be done by the original author or the moderators. The fallback at this time is a combination of the same crowdsourcing, since there is a similar vote process to reopen, or the moderators who can override those actions. I absolutely agree that ideology is a bad reason to edit or close, though people will upvote or downvote on whatever criteria they consider make a "good" question or answer.

I understand the motivation - to have well respected and unambiguous answers from SE (referenced by Google search, Wiki, and others).  But from the point of view of practical search results, "closed" questions don't make much sense. People do see them in Google search results, but don't quite understand why they are marked as closed.

@rushi: I'm not sure whether the cost plays into it, but I agree that folks, probably including myself, are too quick to click close when their reaction would be better expressed by down voting. And in particular, that might be the better response for the "push a personal philosophy" case; just download as bad question.

@keshlam "I'm not sure whether the cost plays into it" - The cost is the key, I think. People are getting instant gratification (almost for free) by having the power to shut someone off (click Close). Especially if they are not highly respected members of the community. And this disruptive dynamic helps to shut down the activity of the best contributors. I saw it in the Space Exploration meta where weeks passed by without an interesting question/discussion.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: I dunno. Maybe because I don't buy into the gamificarion, but I honestly don't think in terms of points. There may be some gratification in thinking that they are helping administer the site, which of course only works if they are doing it well... But I agree that any behavior which is rewarded, in any manner, gets reinforced. I'd be perfectly happy to see close votes scored as -2, like downvotes, maybe -4 if we agree that down should be used more often than close, so folks are spending rep rather than earning it. But I don't think SE supports that...?

@keshlam: We probably can't do that. The more realistic option is to reword or remove the "push a personal philosophy" close reason, or else do nothing (if we don't agree there's a problem with that close reason in the first place).

I agree that it looks like this one needs rewording. I am not sure we yet understand our goal well enough to achieve that, though maybe if we throw out enough possibilities that could help us crystallize that understanding.

Broadly speaking we can categorize questions into two types:

Is philosophical idea X true?
Did (philosopher/school of thought) Y say or mean X?

Questions of type (2) are absolutely on-topic; they typically have a clear answer that someone who knows about Y can give. They may quote or reference a philosophical text (although just doing so does not necessarily make a question type (2)). Type (2) questions are also, if you ask me, a little dry.
Questions of type (1) are opinion-based. This is philosophy; with enough effort anyone can take and justify any position on at least three sides of any issue. On a popular type (1) question you will see this in the answers. Most questions of type (1) are also personal philosophies, in the sense that the author of the question came up with the idea themselves rather than reading about it somewhere else. And yet, good type (1) questions are popular and interesting.
On the front page right now, sorted by activity, I see these questions of type (1):

Is giving simpler hypotheses higher prior probabilites the only way to define a probability distribution over hypotheses?
Can we judge morality?
Does Solomonoff's theory of inductive inference justify Occam's razor?
Is there a principle in the “always”?
Does having compatibles world views solve all social problems?
If the laws of nature are not metaphysically fundamental, what alternative explanations could account for the regularities observed in nature?
Can there be a solution to these three problems?
Can one justifiably believe in the correctness of a mathematical theorem without relying on empirical evidence?
Does randomness interrupt causal chains? [duplicate]
What elements of a causal chain act as explanations for an effect?
Is there just one Zero?
The initial point of everything
Can we evaluate claims reliably and with a high degree of consensus without empirical evidence?
How much of a structural/syntactic difference is there between an oath and a promise?
Can an exception ever "prove" a rule?
Can an argument be true while having logical errors?
The coherence of physicalism: are there any solutions to Hempel's dilemma? (NOTE: this does reference and quote a philosophical text)
Fine-tuning argument and stochastic independence [closed]
Are two persons equally rational in choosing different dogmatic stopping points in their chains of justification as per the Münchhausen trilemma?
Causality and Free-Will
What is the definition of physical? Is that definition clear enough to make a distinction between physical and non-physical?
How do we determine our actual degree of belief?
Is there greater explanatory power in laws governing things rather than being descriptive? [closed]
Is there a term for the fact that it may need more information to describe a probability distribution than conveyed by the event itself?
What are the ontological implications of that “the universe is not locally real” in quantum mechanics?
Is a finite and acyclic causal model of the world logically consistent? [closed]
Is it implausible to claim consciousness is a fundamental?
Is the tyrannicide perpetrated by William Tell morally legitimate?
Are there laws of Nature?
When is a vigilante response to injustice, morally justified?
Does the Munchhausen trilemma allow someone to uphold any belief? [duplicate]

I see these questions of type (2):

Does Hume propose that causes might actually just be explained by coincidence?
What does Baudrillard mean by "The end of the Social"?
Looking for the name of Philsopher or Philosophy/Book/Thesis from around Enlightnement period about human inclicnation to tribalism
What is the difference between praxis and poiesis?
Frege On sense and Reference - question about something Frege says about Sense vs Ideas
What's the difference between ontical and ontological?
"Either a Platonist or an Aristotelian"
How do mathematical realists explain the applicability and effectiveness of mathematics in physics?
Isn't Gaunilo's Lost Island God itself?
Does anyone have a source that refers to Gödel and Kant with respect to the incompleteness theorems? (In simple language for physicists)
Nietzsche about philosophical Realism
Has Giaquinto been refuted?
Looking for a Nietzsche quote!

And these questions are a little borderline or hard to categorize:

Are thoughts qualia? (borderline because it is asking about the definition of a term in common usage, but on the other hand it is including a lot of personal thoughts)
How to get online proof writers working?
Was the concept of omnipotence, per that specific word, originally meant to refer to "all possibilities"? (borderline because in theory the title question might be answered by a historian, but on the other hand the post is including a lot of personal thoughts)

We can see that most questions are of type (1). Not only that, but the most active questions - the ones at the top of the list sorted by "activity" - are even more disproportionately type (1); the first type (2) question is something like a dozen entries down the front page. Only one of the type (1) questions, from a brief perusal, seems to be primarily about whether some academic philosopher is right; the rest of them are primarily the thoughts of the asker. That makes them both opinion-based and personal philosophies.
But we can see that few of these type (1) questions are closed. In practice, in my experience, most type (1) questions that are closed as expressing a personal philosophy, are closed because:

They express an unpopular view.
They express too involved or lengthy reasoning.
They are worded naively. If someone comes out and says the words, "Am I right?" or "What do you think?" then it's likely the question will be closed. All type (1) questions are implicitly asking "Am I right?" and "What do you think?" but only the naive ones come out and say it.
They are from a user who is disliked.
They reflect disorganized thinking.
They are formatted and expressed in a nonstandard way (long numbered lists of propositions as if they were Wittgenstein, large bolded headings, etc.)

Myself, I have no objection to type (1) questions, provided they express a clear enough idea. They are the most common type of question people come to this site to ask, and they are often popular and highly upvoted. The site would be quite boring if we only had type (2) questions. When a reasonably clear type (1) question gets a lot of votes to close, it makes you wonder why that question.

"They are from a user who is disliked" how does that happen in the first place? Seems dislike has to be earned in some way.

@tkruse I do not wish to discuss that here. But speaking generally, selective enforcement of a rule against people the enforcers don't like is a bad thing. You want the police to act that way?

Police officers are tasked with maintaining order and safety. Having a closer look on repeat offenders giving them more scrutiny seems a useful and efficient strategy in achieving that goal.

@tkruse Now you're shifting the goalposts from "people the enforcers don't like" to "people who are repeat offenders." When the enforcers act on personal bias or dislike for a person or group of people to give them harsher punishments for the same crime, that's a bad thing.

Again, where would a negative opinion in an asker come from other than past behavior? It could be that they were pushing personal beliefs in the past, or otherwise violate social conventions.

Imagine there is a street where people jaywalk every day - dozens of them. Maybe there should be a crosswalk there. Three police officers are standing by watching everybody jaywalk, without comment. Then one guy - Jerry - crosses the street and the officers immediately arrest him for jaywalking. Why? Well, he's a repeat offender - they've arrested him for jaywalking in the past many times! Incidentally the officers don't like the slogan on his shirt, and he's often given them the middle finger when they arrest him. The officers return to the street, satisfied they're maintaining the peace.

I saw a user being counseled that "no one is being murdered here" when they started drawing exceedingly dramatic analogies, so it's probably worth mentioning that a downvote is an individual assessment of appropriateness, not a police action to enforce a rule. The famous "state's monopoly on violence" is clearly in play in police actions, but doesn't seem appropriate here.

I have zero clue what your point is. Nor do I have any clue about what Mind-Reading device you have been using to know who votes why.

@JonathanZ it’s obviously just an analogy. Every analogy has differences. The point is that if a user closes a question as off topic and does not close another question as off topic, but both questions seem off topic, then they are being inconsistent.

There cannot be any notion of "letting somebody off with a warning because it's their first time" that maintains individual consistency of action. If all get a first warning, there is still consistency per person though.

Since you seem optimistic that participants' awareness of wrong-doing might diminish said wrong-doing, I would start with the following, and am very amenable to language modification.

The question uses loaded language or is suggestive. If the question essentially prejudices certain reasonable responses or answers itself, then question may function as a rhetorical question. For instance, if a question opens accusing professional philosophers as corrupt or certain historical figures like Kant of being incompetent and then suggests the answer, it is a pushy question.
The question is condemnatory, accusatory, or conspiratorial. For instance, if the question opens with comments about scientists operating as a cabal to suppress truth, and then proceeds to ask about some of their flawed views, it is a pushy question.
The question essentially dumps a contributor's beliefs and asks for validation or feedback. For example, if someone comes and offers their views on reincarnation and ends the question with "What does you think?", it's a pushy question.
The question is a minor variation of previously asked and answered questions. For example, a user posts several questions in quick succession: why do scientists believe X? why do scientists not believe Y as an alternative to X? Why do so many non-scientists believe Y when scientists believe X? While each question might be an honest ask, collectively, they become pushy questions.
The question demands responses conform to unreasonable standards or certain type of responses in the face of a breadth of ways to respond. For example, a user asks the question "Why is probability useless? and do not tell me it is not and only answers with citations from astrology.com" is a pushy question because it essentially resists reasonable push back that probability theory has utility, and it is looking for citations from a biased site.
The question uses heavily biased references or presumes controversial commitments to truth. Consider the question "Why do people who pretend there are Palestinians and are violating Israeli rights according to Barauch Goldstein not qualify as anti-Semites?" This is a pushy question.
The question uses heavily idiosyncratic terminology that stretches normal semantics or outright rejects conventional definitions. For example, "Why does consciousness fail to be considered X, when by consciousness I mean the biological processes of plants and mushrooms."
The questioner uses the comments to badger and criticize answers given in good faith. In a comment, the OP says things like "Clearly you don't understand my question because I meant X" or "This answer seems clearly misguided since you don't understand X."
The question is obviously the poster's homework assignment and no effort has been put into trying to answer it. For example, According to my professor, X said Y. In 500 words or less, why did X believe Z made Y true?"


Just to throw out a possible digression, which might actually want to be a new question:
I have always been somewhat uncomfortable with the argument that "bad questions"  should be closed rather than answered with explanations of why they are bad.
That's certainly valid for off topic questions, since without it the ability to find relevant questions and answers breaks down, as does the ability to call questions to the attention of the folks best able to answer them.
For questions that are on topic, I think the argument is that bad questions should be edited into better form before being answered. On other stacks, that takes the form of close reasons that explicitly ask for more detail or more focus.
The "pushing a personal philosophy/doing philosophy rather than discussing philosophy" close reasons do not seem to be of the "please clarify" form. They are closer to declaring the question off topic. While I believe that the goal is to try to prevent unresolvable flame wars, especially over theology, I do wonder whether that is the best way to do it. Sending the theology questions over to a theology stack would strike me as the better answer, except that the overlap between philosophy and theology has historically been strong enough that separating the two on any line except whether God or religion or creation is explicitly mentioned may be difficult, and that line does not accurately track the distinction.
It may be time to take a step back and explicitly ask what the actual bounds are that we are trying to draw for the stack, whether they really need to be exercised preemptively via close, and how to write policies which specifically addresses those issues and, as much as possible, only those issues. And which give better guidance on how to write questions so they meet those guidelines, or when to take a question elsewhere.
And in some cases, I wonder if what is really needed is stronger enforcement of the SE practice that comments are supposed to be used to refine an answer, not to debate an answer. In that model, answers one actively disagrees with should arguably simply be downvoted, and another answer giving the preferred response posted separately for others to upvote or downvote. Admittedly, this is harder to enforce; it requires either activist moderators trimming comment chains or more actively taking things to chat. But in many cases, I think the problem that I have seen has been more in the arguments over answers then in the questions or answers themselves, and we have fewer tools to manage that other than trying to keep the arguments from starting or continuing.
(Reminder, in case anybody isn't aware of it, that comments are not considered part of the long-term content of Stack Exchange, and officially may evaporate at any time; if you want disagreement on record, down voting and posting a competing answer, and if necessary flagging for moderator attention, are the mechanisms that have been provided for this.)
So: what is our actual goal, how can we best use the mechanisms SE provides to achieve that goal, and if those mechanisms are inadequate what can we do about it, if anything?
And, yeah, should I make this a new question?

I think what is really needed is for a couple users to take a breath and not ask one question directly following from another like chainsmokers on their last day on death row. That might improve the reception they get for the fewer and better and not so "but he said..." questions that result. AmIRight? :-)

@ScottRowe: I think part of the problem may be that what they are looking for is a conversation, and that really isn't what Stack Exchange is set up for. We we ask for one question per Question, and we focus comments on refining questions and answers; we actually tell people that if they have additional questions they should break up into multiple Questions and if answers raise new questions they should do likewise rather than discussing them in the comments. If someone is really looking for exploration, that will produce question storms. SE just isn't designed for that.

SE's stated ambition was to be a crowd sourced   FAQ site. The focus was intended to be on short, ideally widely applicable, questions that were amenable to finding a relatively small number of relatively definitive answers. Hence, I think, the statement that what we are trying to do here in the philosophy stack is to answer questions about philosophy rather than to "do philosophy". That isn't what everyone is looking for, clearly, and like most human behavior, and most reality, it's impossible to draw or explain clear boundaries. Pardon the pun: trying to draw a line is stretching the point

As has been noted, meta is a somewhat awkward exception.

I hate having to tell enthusiastic people that they may be in the wrong place, and they generally do not react overly well to being told they need to back off a bit and change their style. But the guy who breaks into a cool jazz solo in the middle of a classical orchestra is going to get an uncomfortable reception, independent of how much people like him and / or like what he's playing.

Just had such a conversation, when someone objected to my suggesting that these days a factual question on the nature of time might better be explored in cosmology, though exploring the implications on a human scale still strikes me as a valid topic for non-science philosophy. They unfortunately took major offense. Not much I can do about that now, beyond reminding them that it was only a suggestion and wishing them well.

I think no one mentioned the manner in which some of those "philosophical" questions were met and aggressively closed (within an hour(s) of opening). I think we could deal with discord in scientific ideas more politely. Even if the question expresses some of the unpopular views, but contains intelligent presentation and people with a high reputation are already engaged in answering this question, there is no harm to letting it linger for a day or two. You can always close it later on.

The whole point of closing a question is to prevent answers to a bad/off-topic/etc question. Closing it after people have more or less finished interacting with it is like closing the gates after the animals have all escaped. If a question should be closed, why wait?

@fyrepenguin - When people are trying to shut you off, it could be a good sign. I went through that on Space meta, and my frustration was graciously compensated with some critical information for my article.

I don't think we should go this way. At the 50,000 foot level, unsuitable questions should be closed; suitable questions should not be closed. Period. What we should be discussing/arguing/fighting-over is what and how those categories detail out. As a teacher I can tell you, arguing over "grace marks for passing" is a bad idea

Space meta? Or just the space SE?

@Rushi - "and who are the judges?". In this polarized world with high emotions on both sides, I guess it would require some form of arbitration, respected by both sides.

@MisterMiyagi The "don't close discussion" is not  exclusively about 1 user. It just so happens that user is fighting back a bit more loudly. And another

@MisterMiyagi - I think you are confusing software coding "questions/answers" that often are "right or wrong", with philosophical "questions/answers" that are more often in a gray area.

@MisterMiyagi - I've been told that in this meta "philosophical" questions are not welcome. Only questions "about philosophy" are allowed. But a significant minority disagree.

Why not? A lot of people are confused, especially if you are new to Philosophy meta.

@MisterMiyagi - Stack Overflow 49.8k - I guess, not completely randomly.
